# How to validate bcrypt password in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have a change password form with fields for old and new password
The old password field is named `old_password`.

In my controller i am validating the passwords like this

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'old_password' => 'required|min:6|exists:users,password',
            'password' => 'required|min:6:max:30',
]);
```

But its not working as im comparing the `old_password` directly with password without function `bcrypt()`.

So how can i compare the `old_password` field with the already stored bcrypted password in user field.

> Note: i want to give the validation error back that password does not
>   match if it is different

Comment: you need to use custom validation rule for that or extend validator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would make such a function

The HTML form

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/admin-admin-password-update/'.$admin->id) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('new_password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="new_password" class="form-label">New Password (Minimum of 6 characters. No spaces.) <span class="required-alert">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" id="new_password" />

        @if ($errors->has('new_password'))
            <div class="help-block">
                 {{ $errors->first('new_password') }}
            </div>
       @endif

   </div>
   <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('confirm_password') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="confirm_password" class="form-label">Confirm New Password <span class="required-alert">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" />

        @if ($errors->has('confirm_password'))
            <div class="help-block">
                 {{ $errors->first('confirm_password') }}
            </div>
       @endif

  </div>
  <div class="form-group clearfix">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save New Password</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

controller code

```
public function updatePassword(Request $request)
{
    $this->admin = Auth::user();
    $this->id   = $this->admin->id;

    $this->validate($request, [
       'current_password'   => 'required',
       'password'           => 'required|min:6',
       'confirm_password'   => 'required|same:password',
    ]);

    if (Hash::check($request->input('current_password'), $this->admin->password)) {
        $this->admin->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));

        $this->admin->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Your password has been updated.');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'The current password you provided could not be verified');
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx for providing complete example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the hash results of both `old_password` and the other password you wish to compare.

```
// when old_password is not encrypted but other_password is:
bcrypt('old_password') === hash_of_other_password
```

One way of doing so with `$this->validate` and not writing custom rules would be to use `$request->merge()`. That way you can use the `confirmed` rule or even `exists` if you have the hashed value stored in your database.

Comment: While this might work it's not good practice as it may allow timing attacks to help determine the type of hash algorithm used.